# Is the "loop unrolling" in OpenCL implicit or explicit?

Tags: opencl

I have tried adding `#pragma unroll` and `#pragma unroll <loop count>` in my OpenCl code but I don't see any improvement in latency. Statements inside the loop are independent and should run in parallel. So, I want to know if OpenCL is implicitly unrolling the loops and that adding the unroll pragma won't help.

Part of my code is like this

```
for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    m[0][j]   = p0[j] + p0[j+4];
    m[0][j+4] = p0[j] - p0[j+4];
    m[1][j]   = p1[j] + p1[j+4];
    m[1][j+4] = p1[j] - p1[j+4];
    m[2][j]   = p2[j] + p2[j+4];
    m[2][j+4] = p2[j] - p2[j+4];
    m[3][j]   = p3[j] + p3[j+4];
    m[3][j+4] = p3[j] - p3[j+4];
}
```

I'm using OpenCL 2.0.

The code after manual unroll is like this

```
m[0][0]   = p0[0] + p0[0+4];
m[0][0+4] = p0[0] - p0[0+4];
m[1][0]   = p1[0] + p1[0+4];
m[1][0+4] = p1[0] - p1[0+4];
m[2][0]   = p2[0] + p2[0+4];
m[2][0+4] = p2[0] - p2[0+4];
m[3][0]   = p3[0] + p3[0+4];
m[3][0+4] = p3[0] - p3[0+4];

m[0][1]   = p0[1] + p0[1+4];
m[0][1+4] = p0[1] - p0[1+4];
m[1][1]   = p1[1] + p1[1+4];
m[1][1+4] = p1[1] - p1[1+4];
m[2][1]   = p2[1] + p2[1+4];
m[2][1+4] = p2[1] - p2[1+4];
m[3][1]   = p3[1] + p3[1+4];
m[3][1+4] = p3[1] - p3[1+4];

m[0][2]   = p0[2] + p0[2+4];
m[0][2+4] = p0[2] - p0[2+4];
m[1][2]   = p1[2] + p1[2+4];
m[1][2+4] = p1[2] - p1[2+4];
m[2][2]   = p2[2] + p2[2+4];
m[2][2+4] = p2[2] - p2[2+4];
m[3][2]   = p3[2] + p3[2+4];
m[3][2+4] = p3[2] - p3[2+4];

m[0][3]   = p0[3] + p0[3+4];
m[0][3+4] = p0[3] - p0[3+4];
m[1][3]   = p1[3] + p1[3+4];
m[1][3+4] = p1[3] - p1[3+4];
m[2][3]   = p2[3] + p2[3+4];
m[2][3+4] = p2[3] - p2[3+4];
m[3][3]   = p3[3] + p3[3+4];
m[3][3+4] = p3[3] - p3[3+4];
```

Comment: did u try __attribute__((opencl_unroll_hint(n)))? https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.0-openclc.pdf

Comment: Tried that just now, doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try manual unrolling?

Comment: No, I did not try that.

Comment: Well, what happens if you unfold the loop then?

Comment: Ok, so manual unrolling does reduce latency.

Comment: Does it loop for a compile time constant number like 4 or some unknown runtime value?

Comment: It's a compile time constant, e.g., 8. That's why I can unroll the loop manually.

Comment: I just unrolled another loop, manually, but I don't see any gain. To test the timing thoroughly, I run the code multiple times.

Comment: Could you put the no-gain unroll and performant unroll kernel codes in question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably compiler is unrolling, but not re-ordering instructions to have best performance.

Maybe it's not about instruction level parallelism nor filling-pipelines.

Maybe it's about memory access patterns.

Just in case of compiler's inability or re-ordering instructions, here is example:

```
m[0][0]   = p0[0] + p0[0+4];  <---- contiguous   addr = x
m[0][0+4] = p0[0] - p0[0+4];
m[1][0]   = p1[0] + p1[0+4];
m[1][0+4] = p1[0] - p1[0+4];
m[2][0]   = p2[0] + p2[0+4];
m[2][0+4] = p2[0] - p2[0+4];
m[3][0]   = p3[0] + p3[0+4];
m[3][0+4] = p3[0] - p3[0+4];

m[0][1]   = p0[1] + p0[1+4];  <---- contiguous   addr = x+1
m[0][1+4] = p0[1] - p0[1+4];
m[1][1]   = p1[1] + p1[1+4];
m[1][1+4] = p1[1] - p1[1+4];
m[2][1]   = p2[1] + p2[1+4];
m[2][1+4] = p2[1] - p2[1+4];
m[3][1]   = p3[1] + p3[1+4];
m[3][1+4] = p3[1] - p3[1+4];

m[0][2]   = p0[2] + p0[2+4];  <---- contiguous   addr = x+2
m[0][2+4] = p0[2] - p0[2+4];
m[1][2]   = p1[2] + p1[2+4];
m[1][2+4] = p1[2] - p1[2+4];
m[2][2]   = p2[2] + p2[2+4];
m[2][2+4] = p2[2] - p2[2+4];
m[3][2]   = p3[2] + p3[2+4];
m[3][2+4] = p3[2] - p3[2+4];

m[0][3]   = p0[3] + p0[3+4];  <---- contiguous   addr = x+3
m[0][3+4] = p0[3] - p0[3+4];
m[1][3]   = p1[3] + p1[3+4];
m[1][3+4] = p1[3] - p1[3+4];
m[2][3]   = p2[3] + p2[3+4];
m[2][3+4] = p2[3] - p2[3+4];
m[3][3]   = p3[3] + p3[3+4];
m[3][3+4] = p3[3] - p3[3+4];
```

so if it is failing because of this, you can try this:

```
m[0][0]   = p0[0] + p0[0+4];
m[0][1]   = p0[1] + p0[1+4]; 
m[0][2]   = p0[2] + p0[2+4];
m[0][3]   = p0[3] + p0[3+4];
...
```

and re-order the rest similarly so for all arrays, mem accesses are better. But I'm not sure about m array since it could be row-major or column-major depending on device.